# React - Modal expands div in footer div not on main screen

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog

New to coding, trying to get a modal to work. It is not opening the way I expected it to.

The component is currently loaded within the footer div of my site. And when the button is toggled it simply hides or shows a div within the footer. I want it to appear in the centre of the webpage as a modal.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './policy.css'

export default function Policy() {
    const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);
  
    const toggleModal = () => {
      setModal(!modal);
    };

  if(modal) {
    document.body.classList.add('active-modal')
  } else {
    document.body.classList.remove('active-modal')
  }

    return (
    <>
    <div>
        <button onClick={toggleModal} className='btn-modal'>
            <p>Privacy Policy</p>
        </button>
    </div>

    {modal && (
 <div className="modal">
    <div onClick={toggleModal} className="overlay"></div>
        <div className="modal-content">
                <h2>Privacy Policy</h2>
                <p>This is the privacy policy</p>
                <button className='close-modal' onClick={toggleModal}>Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )}
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve a modal effect is to use some CSS.

You could try a very crude style like (from MUI Modal [docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-modal/#basic-modal)):

```
const style = {
  position: "absolute",
  top: "50%",
  left: "50%",
  transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
  width: 400,
  bgcolor: "lightgrey",
  border: "2px solid #000",
  boxShadow: 24,
  padding: 4,
};
```

Then apply it to your modal:

```
<div className="modal" style={style}>
```